# BufferSize location in log4j xml configuration

Tags: java, log4j

I have the following in my log4j.xml configuration:

```
<appender name="FileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="${MDCapture.logfile.dir}/${APP_NAME}.log"/>
    <param name="BufferedIO" value="false"/>
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MMM-dd"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.TTCCLayout">
        <param name="DateFormat" value="ISO8601"/>
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="AsyncAppenders" class="org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender">
    <appender-ref ref="FileAppender"/>
    <param name="BufferSize" value="1000" />
</appender>
```

When I run it, I get the following warning:

> 08-Apr-2013 14:22:15
>   log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 18 and column 13
>   log4j:WARN The content of element type "appender" must match "(errorHandler?,param*,rollingPolicy?,triggeringPolicy?,connectionSource?,layout?,filter*,appender-ref*)".

Do I need to move  as follows:

```
<appender name="FileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="${MDCapture.logfile.dir}/${APP_NAME}.log"/>
    <param name="BufferedIO" value="false"/>
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MMM-dd"/>
    <!-- HERE -->
    <param name="BufferSize" value="1000" /> 
    <!-- END HERE --> 
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.TTCCLayout">
        <param name="DateFormat" value="ISO8601"/>
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: what is the log4j jar version that you are using?

Answer (score 4):

Well, I only see 13 lines of code, but

```
<appender name="AsyncAppenders" class="org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender">
    <appender-ref ref="FileAppender"/>
    <param name="BufferSize" value="1000" />
</appender>
```

has `<appender-ref>` and `<param>` tags in the wrong order.

WARN The content of element type "appender" must match "(errorHandler?,**param***,rollingPolicy?,triggeringPolicy?,connectionSource?,layout?,filter*,**appender-ref***)".

Answer (score 0):

to use BufferSize, you must have log4j v1.2.17 at least. Please check the jar version that you are using.

Comment: ah, I'm using 1.2.15. otherwise it looks okay?

Comment: yes, otherwise it looks ok, try with 1.2.17 check if it is working or not.

Comment: what server are you using?, are you sure that it does not contain an older log4j jar in its lib directory?

Comment: server? it's a stand alone java application. I use commons-logging-1.1.1.jar with it. No other logging libraries.

Comment: If I use <param name="BufferSize" value="1000" /> in <appender name="FileAppender>....</appender> I get no warnings.

Comment: very interesting. If I swap order (i.e include BufferSize before <appender-ref ref=... /> , seems to work without upgrading log4j library

Comment: hmm, swap the order in that case :)